# Difficulty with closing (or hiding) a modal after an ajax call.

Tags: jquery, ajax, hide

I have a simply function below -  its sends some data to a php script and then what I want it to do is hide a div of the class "reveal-modal-refer" and load a short script '../message_alerts/refer_message_box.php' into the div of class 'reveal-modal-refer-message-sent'. My problem is that I keep getting the error in firebug

TypeError: ".reveal-modal-refer-message-sent".load is not a function
scripts_ajax.js (line 76)

(line 76 ==  ('.reveal-modal-refer-message-sent').load('../message_alerts/refer_message_box.php', {result: result});

I am new to jQuery so I apologise if this is straight forward. There are many threads on this kind of thing on Stack, many of which refer to this potentially stemming from conflicting versions of jQuery. I have tested this and it doesn't seem to be the problem.

```
   $(document.body).on("click", "#refer_it", function(){
       var email = $('#refer_input').val();
       var thread_id = $('#thread_id_for_referral').val();
       var user_id = $('#user_id_for_referral').val();   
       $.ajax({
         url: '../email_scripts/refer_email_action_script.php',
         type: 'post',
         data: {
          'email': $('#refer_input').val(),
          'thread_id': $('#thread_id_for_referral').val(),
          'user_id' : $('#user_id_for_referral').val(),
          },
            success: function(html) {
                  var result = "Question sent";

                  $('.reveal-modal-refer').hide();
                  ('.reveal-modal-refer-message-sent').load('../message_alerts/refer_message_box.php', {result: result});                                      
                 }
              });
     return false;
   });
```

Comment: maybe, Did you miss a dollar sign before ('.reveal-modal-refer-message-sent')?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the $ (jquery) before ('.reveal-modal-refer-message-sent') in the load method call:

`success: function(html) {
   var result = "Question sent";
   $('.reveal-modal-refer').hide();
   $('.reveal-modal-refer-message-sent').load('../message_alerts/refer_message_box.php', {result: result});

 }
});`

Comment: Many thanks Pal, will mark as correct in 8 minutes. Arguably a waste of resources asking the question - I should have been more perceptive!